# Convert series to float pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i have a function that is supposed to chain link a list of daily returns in a dataframe, but when i pass the column, the function is returning a series, rather than a float

```
def my_aggfunc(x):
y = np.exp(np.log1p(x).cumsum())
return y
```

if however i change the second line to be

```
np.sum(x)
```

this returns a float

Any ideas pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.log1p(x)` is an array.
`np.log1p(x).cumsum()` is another array of the same size.
`np.exp(np.log1p(x).cumsum())` is yet another array.

I'm assuming you didn't want `cumsum` you wanted `sum`

`np.exp(np.log1p(x).sum())`

Answer (score 0):

From the `np.exp` [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.exp.html):

> Calculate the exponential of all elements in the input array.
>
> **Returns**:   **out** : *ndarray*   Output array, element-wise exponential of x.

So `y` is an array.